Avoid long lines inside nested data uri
I have become a fan of single-file web applications. Now I try to make it installable via an embedded manifest. Ideally I would like

to have the manifest directly editable (i.e. not base 64 - when using base64 here, the lines can be arbitrarily short)
not have very long lines as the icon data URI src attributes

<link rel="manifest" href='data:text/javascript,{"name":"my app name",
"short_name":"appshort",
"start_url":"https://some.url/this.html",
"icons":[{"src":"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg...(a lot more)"
...

The problem that I have is that I can not find a way to break the data:image/png;base64... lines.
Inserting a linebreak inbetween gives a Syntax error at the end of the line (all errors as shown in the DevTools under Application/Manifest).
Putting a \ before a linebreak gives Invalid escape sequence .
Putting \\ before a linebreak gives a Syntax error at the end of the line.
Using a single backtick ` to start and end the data:image/png... (which is a kind of javascript way to say ignore newlines in the string) gives a Syntax error at the start of the string.
I can put \n anywhere inside the long string but of course it will not make the line shorter.
Impossible? Suggestions? Thanks!

Sounds like an X/Y problem. Why do you not want long lines? My editors do not care.
If you must, save the icons as images on a CDN and load them from there

I tested it with a normal image and it seems that HTML is ignoring all whitespace inside the base64 string. That means I can add as many spaces, new lines and tabs as I want inside of it. Have you tried this? So just a linebreak, no escaping, of course. See DEMO, but make the HTML window wide enough to see it properly. This might also work within the JSON inside your link tag..... or not. I think it will.

@mplungjan you are right, jedit gets slow with long lines, that is one of the reasons I do not like them.

@KIKOSoftware I tried that too, but somehow because it is nested it seems it does not work, see edit

You should be able to do
"icons":[{"src":"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg\-~...(a lot more)" where - is a newline and ~ is the next line without any leading spaces

@mplungjan this works outside of the nexted data-uri context, but not inside... :-(
